# Extract data using indicator matrix (binary matrix)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sympy

How can one use a binary matrix in order to get the specific positions in a dataset. So, for example if we took a matrix with categories 1 and 2  looked like this

```
1 2 0 
0 2 1
0 0 2
```

and the original data (`A`) looked like this:

```
a b c 
e f g  
i j k
```

To give me a dataset 1 (using `B1`):

```
a 0 0 
0 e 0
0 0 0
```

and dataset 2 (using `B2`):

```
0 b 0 
0 c 0
0 0 k
```

I have put a template here to try any solution using Sympy or NumPy to test any possible answers:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
init_printing()

a , b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = sym.symbols("a b c d e f g h i")

B1 =  sym.Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]]) # To get dataset 1
B2 =  sym.Matrix([[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]) # To get dataset 2
A =  sym.Matrix([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]])  

B1

1 0 0 
0 1 0
0 0 0 

B2

0 1 0 
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

Comment: are you sure your `dataset 1` is right? I do not understand the question

Comment: Thanks @MarcoP there is an error there. Wrong letter :D I fixed it, the letter is an 'e' not a 'b'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using this "indicator matrix" one could use a nested for loop with a nested if statement. This would let you get to the final answer. It would be inefficient but would still get you the desired result.